# Find out the number of instance

Tags: jquery

My HTML and jQuery codes are like below.

I would like to find out the number of instance of element clicked.

```js
$(".addproduct").click(function() {

  //I would like to find out which element is clicked. First one ? or Second one ? or Third one ?

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="addproduct">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct">product info</div>
<div class="addproduct">product info</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use jQuery [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function.

```
$(".addproduct").click(function(){
   console.log($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('addproduct').click(function(){
    $num = $(this).index();
    conosle.log($num+1);
});
```